# What's going wrong with QT Creator and preventing me from launching it?

Tags: 11.10, ide, debugging

I am not able to start QT Creator. When I start it the following error is given.

```
(qtcreator:8508): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(qtcreator:8508): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(qtcreator:8508): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(qtcreato:8508): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Ih3kweFmKu,guid=af07d35df387caee7e8705270000001a" 
Registered DEC:  true 
Invalid parent:  0xa4f5b78 SharedTools::QtSingleApplication(0xbfee5be0, name = "qtcreator") 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
Requesting child objects for an interface that is a virtual child itself. 
QSpiAdaptor::getChild INVALID CHILD:  QWidget(0xa661398, name = "qt_scrollarea_viewport") 2 
ASSERT: "interface->childCount() == children.count()" in file adaptor.cpp, line 200
Aborted
```

Comment: I think it's a problem with Qt installation. I installed Qt Creator from software center and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

I've found in Nokia developers forums that it is an issue with the Qt version shipped in Ubuntu. More precisely with the style plugin. Anyway, it seems there is a workaround. You should execute the installer with ***-style cleanlooks*** parameter.

> ./Qt_SDK_Lin64_offline_v1_1_4_en.run -style cleanlooks

Comment: can you please give exact commands

Comment: You are right. I think it's better now :)

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the **qt-at-spi** package (build with assertions ON?). Removing it solves the problem but may reduce accesibility features in other software.